# Change EditText Visibility To Hidden

Tags: java, android

I want to change EditText visibility to hidden when a button click. I write a code, but it doesn't work. How can I do it?

This is my code:

```
public void onClick(View view) {
        if(((Button)findViewById(R.id.login)).getId() == ((Button)view).getId())
            findViewById(R.id.google_account).setVisibility(0); 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set EditText  `View.GONE` as:

```
EditText txtx=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.google_account);
txtx.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

or

```
findViewById(R.id.google_account).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Answer (score 5):

0 means `visible`.

It's better to use the constants:

`View.VISIBLE`, `View.GONE` or `View.INVISIBL`.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html

Answer (score 1):

Try this `findViewById(R.id.google_account).setVisibility(View.GONE);`  And here is the full [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#GONE).

Answer (score 1):

```
public void onClick(View view) {
        if((Button)findViewById(R.id.login) == view)
            findViewById(R.id.google_account).setVisibility(View.GONE); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We have constants like `View.INVISIBLE`,`View.VISIBLE`, `View.GONE`, we can also use integer constants like Visible = 0 , Gone = 8 etc...

Eg:

```
public void onClick(View view) {
        if(((Button)findViewById(R.id.login)).getId() == ((Button)view).getId())
            findViewById(R.id.google_account).setVisibility(View.GONE); 

                                  OR

            findViewById(R.id.google_account).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); 
}
```